# Is there away to redirect an API response made by one page request to another in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm posting data to an internal API which queries a DB to find a match and retrieves the rest of the data in the columns.I want the result of the query to be redirected to another page for display.

```
 async function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
     
  const info = {referall,vclass,cover,coverPeriod} 

  const res = await axios.post("/api/setquote", info);
  if (res.status === 200){
   

    router.push('/pick-product')
  
  }else{
    alert('product does not exist')
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite easy I just needed to use the useRouter hook and pass in the result as a query parameter then call in the getintialprops of the page I'm redirecting to.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).